# CSVHelper assigning Record Numbers

Tags: .net, csv, csvhelper

I'm using the CSVHelper library to read in a csv file for processing. When the file is read in, I'd like to track the RecordNumber (or RowNumber) of the record, so if there is a failure, the end user will know what part of the file is to blame.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

```
var rowCount = 0;
var list = new List<MyType>();
while( csv.Read() )
{
    rowCount++;
    var record = csv.GetRecord<MyType>();
    list.Add( record );
}
```

There is also detailed information available on the exception.

```
catch( Exception ex )
{
    var info = ex.Data["CsvHelper"];
}
```

This includes the row number, field number, etc.